# sql group by where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

lets say i have this table

```
user|group|acceptance
1   | a   | -1
2   | a   | 2
3   | b   | 1
4   | b   | 2
5   | b   | 2
6   | c   | -1
```

how do i get count how many users in each group have acceptance not -1 but still list the group having 0 count

so result would be like

```
group | count
a     | 1
b     | 3
c     | 0
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [group], SUM(CASE acceptance WHEN -1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [count]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [group]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Count(Col)` doesn't count NULL values. So pass a non null value where acceptance <> -1 (and it will default to passing null for the case not handled)

```
SELECT [group], 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acceptance <> -1 THEN 1 END) AS [count] 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY [group]
```